# What's the difference between articulatory features and articulatory gestures?

Tags: articulation, spoken-language

I'm confused about those two terms, but based on my understanding articulatory gestures are represented by the vocal tract variables and articulatory features include all units are involved in articulation, such as dental, lips, apical, etc. Also, the vocal tract variables can produce the articulatory features based on a certain model:

|Vocal Tract Variables (articulatory gestures) | ---(MODEL)----> | Articulatory features|

Is that correct so far?

Comment: Gestures are actual motions of actual physical body parts, occurring at some actual time and place and performed by some actual human being. They're **real**, in other words. Features, on the other hand, are useful abstractions that don't exist in actual physical reality, but rather serve as generalizations -- rules of thumb (or tongue) -- to describe some phonological phenomena. Many of the features have names that represent some part of a gesture; that's natural enough. After all, one is sposta represent the other, so it's useful to name them the same.

Comment: I don't see any point in distinguishing the two, unless you're doing a linguistic analysis of phonologists' use of terms.  But that is not about language -- it's about linguists.

Comment: @GregLee But linguists' use of language is also a part of language, right? :P

Comment: @WavesWashSands, No. The truth but not the grammaticality of a linguist's statement is significant,

Comment: @GregLee I mean, you said '...unless you're doing a linguistic analysis of phonologists' use of terms. But that is not about language...' But surely phonologists' use of technical English terms is part of the English language (just as biologists', historians', politicians' and engineers' word uses are) :P

Comment: @WavesWashSands, That's why I added the "unless" clause.  But describing a linguist's speech is a totally different activity from commenting on his theoretical proposals.  For the latter, it doesn't even matter what language is being used.